# Laravel & Vue.js Form Validation Errors

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I am getting a continuous validation error despite the data being valid. I originally had this forming working, at the time I was only storing one email at a time. When I added the "addNewRow" function, I was unable to post the data. Each time I get a validation error, I am quite new to Vue, and I'm not sure where I am going wrong with either the post method or my validation.

Here is my controller:

```
public function notifyTeam(Request $request, Agency $id)
{   
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'unique:users|required|email|max:255|unique:agency_emails',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();
    $agency = Agency::where('id', $user->agency_id)->first();
    $subdomain = $agency->subdomain;

    $emails = json_decode($request->getContent('emailArray'), true);

    foreach($emails as $email){
        $authorizedEmails = new AgencyEmail;
        $authorizedEmails->email = $request->email;
        $authorizedEmails->agency_id = $agency->id;
        $authorizedEmails->save();
    }

    // Generate Link 
    // /{subdomain}/register
    // Email the link to specified users
    // vue component

    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
```

And here is my Vue Component:

```
<template>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">

        </div>
        <h1 class="agency_h1 mt-5 mb-5">ASSEMBLE THE TROOPS</h1>
        <form method="POST" @submit.prevent="submit">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
            <label for="email">E-mail Address</label>
            <div class="form-group row" v-for="(field, k) in fields" :key="k">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email[]" v-model="field.email"
                        required placeholder="Add An Email Address">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show sticky-top mt-2" role="alert"
                        v-show="success">
                        Emails Have Been Seent
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show sticky-top mt-2" role="alert"
                        v-if="errors && errors.email">
                        {{ errors.email[0] }}
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mb-2" @click="addNewRow">Add Row +</button>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-5" >Create Your Agency</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                fields: [{
                    email: '',
                }],
                errors: {},
                success: false,
                csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
            }
        },

        methods: {
            addNewRow() {
                this.fields.push({
                    email: '',
                });
            },

        submit() {
            axios.post('/create-team', {
                    emailArray: this.fields
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.fields = {};
                    this.success = true;
                    this.errors = {};
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    if (error.response.status === 422) {
                        this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
                    }
                    console.log('Still not saved');
                });
           },
        }, 
     }

</script>
```

Comment: so you are passing array of emails, so your validation should be for each element of array, `emailArray.*.email => 'unique:users|required|email|max:255|unique:agency_emails',`, here emailArray is the array of emails you are passing from view component.

Comment: Adding that to the validation rule returns a 500 error which is odd to me, any thoughts around this?

Comment: whats the error message written in 500 error

Comment: also check whats inside `$request->all()` when you pass the array to controller

Comment: `500(internal server error)
     (anonymous) @ VM1798:1
     dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:285
     xhrAdapter @ app.js:119
     dispatchRequest @ app.js:765
     Promise.then (async)  
     request @ app.js:542
     Axios.<computed> @ app.js:567
     wrap @ app.js:1131
     submit @ app.js:1973
     submit @ app.js:37795
     invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:40438
     invoker @ app.js:40763
     original._wrapper @ app.js:46122`

Comment: As far as checking the request, I can' t dd() that because I'm not posting anything due to the validation errors.

Comment: this is what is shown in console, would you check the network tab, also I told to check not post here for `$request->all()`